# Display freeform entries with a status on open – on the front end

Tags: plugin-freeform

I'm using this code in my template

```
{% set formHandle = 'toad' %}
                         {% set submissions = craft.freeform.submissions({
                              form: formHandle,
                            status: ["open"],
                         }) %}

                         {# <h3>Submissions for {{ form.name }}</h3> #}


                         {% if submissions is empty %}
                         <h4>There are no submissions</h4>

                         {% else %}

                         <table class="table">

                              <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                        {% set myfield = (submissions|first).fieldMetadata.status('open) %}

                                        <th>{{ myfield.toadName.label }}</th>
                                        <th>{{ myfield.toadProfile.label }}</th>
                                   </tr>
                              </thead>

                              <tbody>

                                   {% for submission in submissions %}
                                   <tr>
                                        <td>
                                             {{ submission.toadName.value }}   
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                             {{ submission.toadProfile.value }}   
                                        </td>
                                   </tr>
                                   {% endfor %}

                              </tbody>

                         </table>

                         {% endif %}
```

But get the error:

```
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S22
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => Unknown column 'sub_freeform_statuses.handle' in 'where clause'
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sub_freeform_statuses.handle' in 'where clause'
```

Is it possible to show just form entries with an open status only? without
 status: ["open"],
the template works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the syntax for one status rather than an array?

```
{% set submissions = craft.freeform.submissions({
      form: formHandle,
      status: "open",
}) %}
```

Ref: http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/template-functions/freeform.submissions.html#param-status

Comment: Thanks John, no tried that I don't understand why its throwing an error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sub_freeform_statuses.handle' in 'where clause'

Comment: Actually I used
{{ submission.toadProfile }} not {{ submission.toadProfile.value }}   syntax and now all good cheers